# mongo authentication with pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm having problems accessing my mongo database through PyMongo. I have the root user and I also created an "app" user for my database. I created a database with two collections. From the mongo shell I can authenticate and query my data. However, when I try with pyMongo, I get "authentication failed".

My python looks like this:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient('mongodb://user:pass@localhost/mydatabase')

db = client.mydatabase
data = db.mycollection.find()
for d in data:
    print(d)
```

The stack output looks like:

```
raise OperationFailure(msg % errmsg, code, response,
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Authentication failed., full error: {'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': 'Authentication failed.', 'code': 18, 'codeName': 'AuthenticationFailed'}
```

I'm sure it's something simple, but I can't figure it out.

Mongo is running in a docker container. I also have Monge Express in another container, and those two talk to each other just fine.

Thanks

Comment: Shell works with the same URI?

Comment: The mongod log should have an entry for that failed login that might provide more detail.